# ROS Problem: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ros

When I run

```
rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node
```

on Ubunto, I got the following message:

> /opt/ros/noetic/lib/turtlesim/turtlesim_node: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys. Below are the steps to solve this problem:

1. Download an X server application for windows because WLS doesn't support graphical interfaces. An example of such X application is Xming (you can download it from https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/)
2. Type the following command in the WLS terminal:
   export DISPLAY=:0

Hopefully, this should work!

Answer (score 5):

I use this method, from https://answers.ros.org/question/354808/error-running-turtlesim-noetic/.

The key point is to be sure to find the location of your libQtCore, and don't copy others' answers directly.

You could try:

```
whereis libQt5Core.so.5
```

copy that address

```
sudo strip --remove-section=.note.ABI-tag /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
```

Comment: Just in case someone wonders across this when trying to install ROS2 from source & they get this error, the above solutions works too

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that libqt5gui5 is installed?
If not, try:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5gui5
```

After installation of the package it should be placed in the proper location that ros could find.